# function clicked not work for me on adminLTE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, adminlte

I got this problem about all night. I will click button and I got nothing data or alert. Please help me. And so Sorry for my bad English.I'll try to learn.

```js
  
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#test-click").on("click",function() { 
        alert('1');
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="test-click">testClick</button>
```

Comment: Try using `event.preventDefault()` inside click event.

Comment: upgrade your jquery library version

Comment: I see "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function" on Console section

Comment: Are you blind? use .live instead of .on event

Comment: @Bhavik Thanks a lot.That work :) .I get jquery-3.1.0 from [link](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes OfCourse! your code is not working. because `.on()` event comes after jquery 1.7.x versions. Please use `.live()` event instead of `.on()` event. Or else use latest jquery version.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test-click").live("click",function(){ 
        alert('1');
    });
    });

</script>
<button type="button" id="test-click">testClick</button>
```

Comment: My fault. I get jquery version 1.6 but now i use 3.1.It's work.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Its working.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#test-click").click(function(){
alert("1");

})
});
```

Comment: My fault. I get jquery version 1.6 but now i use 3.1.It's work.Thanks.